# read a value by its index from a file in C#

Tags: c#, file, double, output, streamwriter

I'm new to programming, so please forgive my naive question .

I have double[ ] array, I manage to write it to text file using the code below:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter outfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Seasonality.txt") )
  {
     for (int raw = 1; raw <54; raw++)
     {
       outfile.Write("{0} ",array[raw]);
     }
  }
```

The output text file (1 raw) consist of 54 records separated by space  as demonstrated below:

```
1.323 2.3443 2.367 5.3453 0.3432 1.754 ........etc
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a function where I read a value by passing its index, i.e. index =1 for the first value in the file, or index =5 for the fifth value in the file etc..

```
Double GetValue (int index) 
{
.....
}
```

P.S: please suggest if you think that changing output file structure to one value per line will ease the task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason that you would not just read the file back into an array and return the appropriate index item from the array?

Comment: yes, I'm programming in a third party application that uses c# (Charting program), it has limitations forcing me to save the array to file to prevent data lost (OnBarUpdate) and read it back whenever required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double GetValue(int index)
{   
   return double.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(your file)[0].Split(' ')[index]);
}
```

Comment: intent was to remove upvote...result unintended.  upvote removed because it seems like recommending `ReadAllLines()` in this method is not great advice.

Comment: @DavidTansey Well, `ReadAllText` would probably be a tad better, but neither will perform any differently.

Comment: Thank you Hossein, I had to adjust it to [index -1] for it to works.

Comment: @illusion I assumed your index is zero based. anyway glad to be helpful.

Comment: @ Hossein Narimani Rad, sorry to disturb you again, everything is working well but getting following exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, since you mention the option of splitting into lines per value - if you did that it would be:

```
var item = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(index-1).First();
```

(plus parsing the final value)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do a few things.

First: Load the file into a string.  You can use File.ReadAllText() or something similar (use the IO streams if you want).

Next you need to parse your data.  You have your items separated by spaces so you're going to want to use stringName.split(' '); where stringName is the variable you use for the file you just loaded and the ' ' represents the character for space (not sure how new you are but " " is a string and ' ' is a character).

Finally you want to grab the correct index, which should actually be the same as you saved the array since you're just reloading it.

Hope this helps!

Edit:  Forgot that you'll need to do the double.parse thing at the end to return your value, as others have shown.

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below,

```
double GetValue(int index)
{
    return double.Parse(File.ReadLines(path).First().Split()[index-1]);
}
```

**Note:**
better you can do more validations for the results of read line, split having enough items to take by given index and use `double.TryParse` to convert.

Comment: Which overload of `Split` takes zero arguments? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: @spender Probably confused with [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx) in which it just splits on any whitespace.

Comment: @2kay: Cool. Learned something today: "If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx